# Read and extract file name from excel cell value

Tags: java, excel

I am having a excel sheet which will have file information like file name , size , last modified date in separate columns . I need to extract file name alone form first column and got to that path and copy that file to other directory using java. Please help me in this

Comment: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) for spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions:

- export the excel file to .csv so that you can parse it in Java
- use a more advanced API such as Apache [POI](http://poi.apache.org), like this:

> ```
> InputStream fis= new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
> Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
> Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
> Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
> Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
> ```

To copy the file, you can use Apache commons' [fileUtils.copy](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Comment: Actually we are giving the excel as input to the java code which will conatin the file name in its column.we need to read that and copy taht file to destination.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this jar library:

https://afajardomorera.github.io/ExcelReader/

You can define a Java Object with the fields you need, configure a property file and invoke the reader method from the jar.

In the github code, you find a jar_generated folder with the latest version of the jar to use it.